# Can Kwin be used in Unity?

Tags: unity, window-manager, kwin, tiling

Unity has a nice layout.  I really do like the Ambiance and Radiance themes.  However, I just feel that the window manager itself is lacking.  KWin has an excellent tiling mode that automatically handles all my window needs without having to drag, resize, or keypress.  I can focus on the information and the work.

My question to you is:  Is there a way to get Kwin or another similar tiling window manager to work within Unity so that I can have the benefits of both worlds?

Comment: KWin and the Compiz/Mutter/Unity family is probably mutually exclusive. I'd suggest that you look into something like awesome, which is a tiling windows manager.

Comment: one possible alternative would be using KDE4 and making it look like Unity, as described in [this German blog](http://maroony.de/blog/2012/02/20/mein-kde-4-8-unity-desktop-3/) (if you don't speak/read German, just take a look at the screenshots there and try to translate the page using e.g. Google translate -- this should at least give you the basic info).

Comment: Unity being a Compiz Plug in won't run if Compiz isn't running, Compiz a Window manager, Kwin is a Window manager, Kwin will replace Compiz and viceversa thus disabling Unity in the process.

Comment: As it has been awhile since I had used Unity, I was not sure if it was still fully created by Compiz.  Thank you @Izzy for the reference to the blog.  That has been a great starting point.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using Unity-2D with KWin for about two weeks now. In the login screen, choose Unity-2D as your session type. Install the `kde-window-manager` package to get `kwin`. Then fire up a terminal and run `kwin --replace &!`. You'll probably want the `systemsettings` and `kde-config-gtk` packages for configuration.

Comment: After running "kwin --replace &!" unity launcher and top panel are gone.